# Turn off server manager on login

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

In Windows Server 2008 R2 there is the "Server Manager" program that always starts up when I log on.  I would like to make it so that this does not start up every time that I log into the server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found [this blog post](http://alensiljak.blogspot.com/2008/12/disable-starting-server-manager-on.html) by Alen Siljak which describes how you can keep it from starting when logging on.  There are two different methods to solve the problem.  The first and most simple is a checkbox in the Server Manager itself.  The second involves modifying the registry, which can be used to automate and script the process for a large number of servers.

1. **UI Method** - In the "Server Manager" program there is the "Server Summary -> Computer Information" section.  At the bottom of the section there is a checkbox "Do not show me this console at logon".  Check this box and exit the program and at next log on you will not see the Server Manager.
2. **Registry Method** - Go to the registry editor and `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ServerManager` and set the variable `DoNotOpenServerManagerAtLogon` to `1`.  Then go to another entry at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\ServerManager` and set the `CheckedUnattendLaunchSetting` to `0` (Note that this will only set it for the current user).  After logging out and logging back on you should no longer see the server manager.

Comment: FWIW the registry method portion of the answer is actually of use to me since I've got a circumstance where several dozen VMs pop up this window unnecessarily and I'm trying to write a script that flips the registry settings for all of them without having to manually click through 40+ checkboxes at a time.

Comment: In cases where the Server Manager opens with a fault and cannot load the MMC, the checkbox is not available to check. If you don't want to fix the fault, but keep the Server Manager from popping up, then the registry method is a great work around.

Answer (score 8):

This behavior can also be suppressed with Group Policy.  From [The Server Manager Main Window](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc770645.aspx#BKMK_SysInfoTile) on TechNet:

> The **Do not show me this console at logon** check box in the **Computer Information** section lets administrators prevent Server Manager from opening automatically when they log on to the computer, if they do not need to see Server Manager at every logon. This behavior can also be controlled by the Group Policy setting **Local Computer Policy/Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Server Manager/Do not display Server Manager automatically at logon**.

Answer (score 6):

On our server, start Server Manager, at top near right pick "Manage", then "Server Manager Properties", and on that screen, check "Do not start Server Manager automatically at logon".

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted answer?

Comment: Its just that little more succinct which allowed me to find the (silly little) checkbox ;) Cheers mate

Comment: @KatherineVillyard On my Windows Server 2012, the option mentioned in the accepted answer simply does not exist, while this one does.

Answer (score 1):

Using skeletank's registry recommendations I created a reg file for the purpose.
It is really simple to use either from batch or just manually.

Just make a text file with .reg extension and copy-paste the next:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ServerManager]
"CheckedUnattendLaunchSetting"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ServerManager]
"DoNotOpenServerManagerAtLogon"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

in "Server Manager" window,  at the top right menu

(click)  Manage > Server Manager Properties
(Window pops up)

(Check) *"Do not Start Server Manager Automatically at logon "*

(Click Ok)

it's Done!!

**note:** i tried it on. "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard - Build 9600".

i wasnt able to find the menu that is mentioned on accepted post. thats why i write it .

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell method:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\ServerManager -Name DoNotOpenServerManagerAtLogon -PropertyType DWORD -Value "0x1" –Force
```